# How to prevent C++ name demangling functions from being included in binary

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, embedded

I am developing firmware for an embedded application on ARM Cortex-M in C++ with GCC 7.3.1 in C++14 mode. There's only 64k of flash available, and my binary wouldn't fit. Looking at the map file I see that there's a function called `__gcclibcxx_demangle_callback` in the binary that takes up 27k flash space. I understand that this is related to C++ name demangling. The linker doesn't discard this symbol although I'm definitely not doing any name demangling in my code. I'm using STL here and there though. How can I eliminate this function to gain some flash space?

I've tried passing `-ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -nostartfiles -fno-rtti` to the compiler and the linker. Passing `-nostdlib` causes the linking to fail even if I pass `-lc -lg -lgcc -lstdc++`.

Comment: Just compile your code in release mode rather than debug?

Comment: What optimization level are you compiling at?

Comment: Try compile your objects with `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections` and link with `-Wl,--gc-sections`, finally run the resulting binary through `strip`

Comment: It's probably related to exceptions built into the STL library.  (probably some catch deep inside STL that's printing out some stuff).    Build with cross referencing turned on so you can see which symbol is requiring it, then find out where it is, etc. etc.  In the end, you might need either recompile the STL without exceptions (why this isn't default in the embedded world toolchains, I have no idea)

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez I'm at -O0 (no optimization) but I don't think that effects linking.

Comment: @Geoffrey All those flags are passed to the respective programs. I'm not getting an ELF file in the end, so there's nothing to run `strip` on.

Comment: You can pass `-y,__gcclibcxx_demangle_callback` to the linker to trace this symbol (hopefully see, why it is included in the resulting binary).

Comment: With only 64k available, my advice is to use C, not C++. It gives you the control you need in such a constrained environment. How much RAM do you have? If it's only a few kilobytes, then I would say you don't even have a choice. Hidd el, ez a dolgom :-)

Comment: @TonyK This is a STM32F407 with 512k flash and 192k SRAM. The flash is partitioned into 64k bootloader (for applying firmware upgrades) + 448k app code. I've been using C++ for the app for a while now, and I wanted the bootloader to be built from the same source, hence C++. So memory is not a problem (for the bootloader at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Russ Schultz's comment got me thinking. Very probably it really was some STL code that used name demangling, and it would have been surprising if there was no other libstdc++ that was more suitable for embedded systems. Apparently, the [GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) provides alternate versions of libstdc++. One is the "nano" version which can be easily used by passing `-specs=nano.specs` to the linker. This reduces the size of the resulting binary drastically (115k to 45k), and roughly looking at the contents, it really includes only necessary symbols. Almost no code bloat apart from some C++ vtables which are tiny anyway.

Answer (score 1):

More options:

```c
-Os -flto  -fno-fat-lto-objects -fuse-ld=gold -fuse-linker-plugin \
-Wl,--icf=all -Wl,--icf-iterations=4 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed \
-Wl,--strip-all -Wl,-O3 -Wl,--orphan-handling=discard -Wl,--no-eh-frame-hdr \
-Wl,--no-ld-generated-unwind-info -fno-unwind-tables
```

*error corrected*
 (`--icf` is specific to "gold")

I'm just learning how myself, but if that doesn't do it you can start modifying the linker script... you can add an "implicit" linker script to the standing defaults by passing it on the link line (ld tries to read anything that doesn't look like object code as a script).  My best guess is you'll want to assign the problem library to its own section, then discard it:
>

> The linker will ignore address assignments (*note Output Section
>   Address::) on discarded output sections, except when the linker script
>   defines symbols in the output section.  In that case the linker will
>   obey the address assignments, possibly advancing dot even though the
>   section is discarded.
>
> The special output section name '/DISCARD/' may be used to discard
>   input sections.  Any input sections which are assigned to an output
>   section named '/DISCARD/' are not included in the output file.

I feel like this really shouldn't be it, but there's also `--no-demangle`...

*edit: if you're trying to compile with `-nostdlib` you might need some combination of `-lgcc_s -lsupc++ -lm`, `` -B `your/compiler/dir` ``, etc*

Comment: `-fuse-linker=gold` is not understood by the linker, it suggests `-fuse-ld=gold`. Passing all those flags results in `collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'`, which is right because the linker should be `arm-none-eabi-ld`. I don't know where this comes from. It could be solved with some shell alias trickery at first sight, but I stopped here because I found a more general solution. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: nod -fuse-linker was a brain fart.  Didn't know gold didn't work for arm compiling, sorry